# TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

Please help me out with below error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined

As I am new in Google Apps Script. i want to generate PDF and send to requester on his email id. Please review my script below and suggest.

```js
function afterformsubmit(e){

const info = e.namedValues;
createPDF(info);
}

function createPDF(info){

const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1nV1zSSJfBND0ao9NufmIOEa_ocO5DhQf");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1u3vbM1hxqKThVMsnjLeLWqLn3CWdTMDO");
const templateDoc   = DriveApp.getFileById("1qBtaAfcsHmxU9Y4wp6uQRdFkR95XhVNqpr6tDQ2xH7Q");
const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
const body = openDoc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{dt}", info['PO Date'][0]);
body.replaceText("{dpt}", info['Department'][0]);
body.replaceText("{rname}", info['Requestor Name'][0]);
body.replaceText("{item}", info['Item 1'][0]);
body.replaceText("{qty}", info['Qty1'][0]);
body.replaceText("{price}", info['Unit price1'][0]);
openDoc.saveAndClose();
const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Requestor Name'][0] + " " + info['Department'][0]);
tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
return pdfFile;
}
```

Comment: Pls also post the code which calls the function `afterformsubmit`. I guess you have passed the wrong `event object` or the property `namedValues` does really not exist like the error shows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the necessary trigger on your project in order to get and use the event object e on your code. To setup the "on form submit" trigger, please follow the steps below:

**1.) In the script editor, go to Edit -> Current project's triggers.**

**2.) On the new tab that appeared, you will see the list of triggers that are manually added by you(if any). To add the "on form submit" trigger, click on "+ Add Trigger" button.**

**3.) On the pop up, select the function that the trigger will run, fill up the other fields, and select "On form submit" as event type. Click Save.**

This should setup the **installable trigger** **"On form submit"** on your project and should allow you to use namedValues on your script.

### Reference

[Event Objects and Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

[Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)